# Add new element to the api method catalogProductCreate

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2

How do I add new element to the api method catalogProductCreate. The element to add is hardness String

Please Help me

Answer (score 2):

If your element is a product attribute, Magento is ready to handle with the Soap API. The [catalogProductCreate](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.create.html) method has `additional_attributes` parameter. You can use it to set one or more values to your attribute using single_data or multi_data.

Example: Add a manufacturer info

```
$newProduct->name = "product name";
$newProduct->description = "description";
$newProduct->short_description = "desc";
$newProduct->status = "1";
$newProduct->price = "99";
$newProduct->tax_class_id = "2";

$newProduct->additional_attributes = array(
    'single_data' => array(
         array(
             'key' => 'manufacturer',
             'value' => 'Company INC',
         ),
     )
);    
/* you can add other additional attributes here like $manufacturer using multi_data parameters */
```

I believe this is enough to solve your problem. But if you really need create a new element in method, you need some customization. You can follow the howto below to create a custom module to override API: https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/How+to+Override+an+Existing+API+Class+with+Additional+Functionality#wsdl